# using localDB with Cordova(Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, localdb

I'm developing a **cross-platform mobile** app using Cordova (Visual Studio 2015)
For the database, I've created a LocalDB using Visual Studio features.
Now, I want to connect to that LocalDB and store data to it, and then select it. While researching through the Internet I did not find how to do this, anyone could help??

the image below shows my local DB
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: by the term localdb which db your mentioning??

Comment: it is the local database I have created inside the Visual Studio

Comment: .mdf file? in App_Data folder?

Comment: yes it is .mdf file and it appears in sever explorer under data connections

Comment: you want to use only that or any alternative you are looking for?

Comment: I just want to use this database if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways listed below to use the database in visual studio.
You need to write a Web Service for that in .NET

1. Asmx service - simple to build
2. WCF service - involves more configuration, but very secured.
3. Asp.Net Web Api - light weight web services for http protocol.

Here is a step by step approach to create a [ASMX service](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_web_services.htm)

For all these services you either use **Entity Framework** or **ADO.NET** for CRUD operations.

I would advise to go with **asmx service using ADO.NET** if your new to .NET.

Comment: thanks for your answer .. but i'm developing a mobile app and the web services items do not appear in the project. should i create a new project with web services and then connect it to my mobile app project?

Comment: Yes for mobile app also you can test them using emulators in vs2015 and you can make a async call through your java script calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer